# An exercise of algebraic topology about Jordan Brouwer Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

Right now I have some problem about the exercise in the chapter of Massey's book, this chapter talks about several important facts about the   $Jordan \space Brouwer \space Theorem$,i.e.,$Let \space A \space be \space a \space subset \space of  \space S^n  \space homeomorphic \space to \space S^{n-1}, then\space S^n -A \space has \space two \space components, and \space the \space boundary\space of \space these\space  components \space are \space A$

The questions are:
1. Show that no proper subset of $S^m$ can be homeomorphic to $S^n,n>m$

2.Prove that any continuous map $f:S^n \to R^n$ cannot be $1-1$

I guess I have to make some calculation about some homology groups, but which space? Or maybe there are other solutions to this problems?

Comment: https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~mozgovoy/data/notes_AT.pdf Corollary 4.10 for 2. The whole section is good for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any homology computation.

About the first question: since $S^n$ must be a proper subset of $S^m$ you have an injection in $S^m \setminus \{ pt\}$ this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ via the usual stereographic projection. Then you can insert $\mathbb{R^m}$ into  $\mathbb{R^n}$ and you finally get an embedding $S^n \hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. There is corollary of Jordan-Brouwer saying that if you have an embedding $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $M$ topological manifold of dimension $n$ then the map is open. Can you end the proof?

For the second question just apply again this corollary.
Or alternatively compose $f$ with the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are you familiar with this concept and what result you get for $\mathbb{R}^n$?